# TSQL Count in select parameter

Tags: .net, t-sql

Given the following query which will give a count of the number of students with the surname Smith for a given enrolment (subject)

```
SELECT 
  e.EnrolmentId,
  COUNT((CASE WHEN s.Surname LIKE 'Smith' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)) AS CountIf
FROM 
  Enrolment e
INNER JOIN StudentEnrolment se
  ON e.EnrolmentId = se.EnrolmentId
INNER JOIN Student s
  ON se.StudentId = s.StudentId
GROUP BY
  e.EnrolmentId
```

Is it possible to have the 'Smith' as a parameter, something like this

```
COUNT((CASE WHEN s.Surname LIKE @Surname THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)) AS CountIf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change COUNT for SUM and the ELSE part for 0 instead of NULL, it should work, no?

```
SELECT 
  e.EnrolmentId,
  SUM((CASE WHEN s.Surname LIKE 'Smith' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS CountIf
FROM 
  Enrolment e
INNER JOIN StudentEnrolment se
  ON e.EnrolmentId = se.EnrolmentId
INNER JOIN Student s
  ON se.StudentId = s.StudentId
GROUP BY
  e.EnrolmentId
```

Example:

```
declare @t as varchar(20)
select @t='ricardo'

declare @ta as table
(
    name varchar(30)
)

insert into @ta
values
('juan'),
('ricardo'),
('pablo')


select
SUM((CASE WHEN name LIKE @t THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS CountIf
from @ta
```

Outputs:

```
CountIf
-----------
1
```

Comment: Looks like the parameter in the select clause will work. Just need to test when being called from .NET code.

Comment: @Craig it will work as well. Should make no difference at all.

Comment: Thanks, I really didn't think parameter in select would work.